# Poisson with its parameter as an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I and many of my class mates are struggling very hard on this problem:

> Let $X$ be a random variable with Poisson distribution, with parameter $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ itself is a random variable with exponential distribution of mean $1/\theta$, that is, $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, $\lambda \sim \exp(\theta)$. Find the marginal distribution of $X$.

I tried:

P(X=x) =  (w.r.t λ from 0 to inf) ∫ P(X=x, λ=θ) = ∫ P(X=x | λ=θ)* P(λ=θ)

And then got stuck a.k.a. something not integrate-able

Help... T.T

Comment: In your attempt you're conditioning on the event $\{\Lambda=\theta\}$. You should be conditioning on the event $\{\Lambda=\lambda\}$ and using the fact that $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)=\theta e^{-\theta \lambda}$ for $\lambda \geq 0$ and $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Oh wow... I see! But how was I supposed to know that it was conditioning on {Λ=λ} and not   {Λ=θ}???

Comment: $\Lambda$ is a random variables that can take on ANY non negative real number. $\Lambda$ does not have to equal $\theta$.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Using total probability yield

$$\mathbb P\{X=k\}=\int_0^{\infty } \mathbb P\left\{X=k\mid \lambda =t\right\}f_\lambda (t)\,\mathrm d t=\frac{\theta }{k!}\int_0^\infty t^ke^{-(1+\theta  )t}\,\mathrm d t, $$
which is integrable.

Several possibilities :

- Brute force, $k$ integration by part is requiert.
- Nevertheless, an antiderivative of $t^ke^{-t}$ is of the form $$(a_0+a_1t+...+a_kt^k)e^{-t}.$$
  So, you can easily find the $a_i$.
- An other way : do the substitution $u=(1+\theta )t$, and write the integral using [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Regardless of approach, it simplifies to $\Bbb P\{X=k\}=\theta/(1+\theta)^{k+1}$, a [zero-indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with $p=\theta/(1+\theta)$.

Comment: Why did you change "an antiderivative" to "the antiderivative"? There are multiple antiderivatives, exactly one of which has the stated form. You could say "the antiderivative vanishing at $\infty$".

Comment: To discuss plurals you'd say something like, "the antiderivatives of $t^ke^{-t}$ are of the form $(a_0+a_1t+\cdots+a_kt^k)e^{-t}+C$". Your correction still doesn't make clear a $+C$ is needed for multiple antiderivatives to take the specified form.

Comment: No, don't erase it.

Comment: In your attempt you're conditioning on the event $\{\Lambda=\theta\}$. You should be conditioning on the event $\{\Lambda=\lambda\}$ and using the fact that $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)=\theta e^{-\theta\lambda}$ for $\lambda\geq0$ and $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @MatthewHolder: No I don't... $\mathbb P\{X=k\mid \lambda =t\}=\frac{e^{-t}t^k}{k!}$ and $f_\lambda (t)=\theta e^{-\theta t}$ as I wrote...

Comment: Whoops. I meant to put this comment under the original posting.

Comment: Oh I see, θ is just a param of exponential distribution. But...
1) It looks like  P{X=k∣λ=t} is same as P{X=x}. How do you go from P{X=x} to P{X=k∣λ=t}? Just substitute t where ever you see λ? Is it really that easy to make a probability density function into a conditional probability density function

Comment: 2) I think we were supposed to solve the Gamma function, but even with the substitution, still unclear how that would lead to a geometric distribution.

Comment: For question 1) obviously not. The connection between $\mathbb P\{X=k\}$ and $\mathbb P\{X=k\mid \lambda =t\}$ is given by the law of total probability : $$\mathbb P\{X\in A,Y\in B\}=\int_B\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y=y\}\mathbb P\{Y\in \,\mathrm d y\}.$$ 2) Then you have all elements to solve your problem ! Honnestly, if $$\Gamma (x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm d t,\quad x>0,$$ it should be to hard to express your expression with Gamma function @Drew

Comment: It should NOT be to hard...

Comment: When I do u-substitution with u = (1+θ), I get ∫ u^x * e^-t. I know that is supposed to somehow become Γ(x+1) [to cancel out with the factorial on the bottom] but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: No, you didn't do well the substitution. @Drew